# DateComponentsFormatter drop zero hours but not zero minutes

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I'm trying to use a `DateComponentsFormatter` to format a number of seconds into a time string HH:MM:SS. I always want to show the minutes and seconds fields but I don't want to show hours if hours is 0. I tried setting

```
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading
```

But, this causes the minutes to be dropped as well if both hours and minutes are 0.

Currently, my solution is as follows:

```
if timeElapsed >= 3600 {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute, .hour]
} else {
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.second, .minute]
}
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
```

However, I'm concerned that this solution is very hacky and won't work correctly if there is some internationalization that doesn't consider one hour to be 3600 seconds. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Your `if` sounds reasonable, why would you call it hacky? An hour is a standard unit of measure, like a meter.

Comment: An hour always has 60 minutes. It's the *day* that sometimes has 23 or 25 hours (i.e. on clock change days for countries that use daylight saving time). Your solution looks OK to me. **Disclaimer:** there's also the [leap second](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/leapseconds.html) if you want to go to the atomic clock level. But it's safe to ignore under most circumstances.