# Custom zero formatting behaviour for date components of elapsed time

Tags: ios, swift

I have a date from which I am calculating the elapsed time, like this:

```
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
if let timeElapsed = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: startTime, to: Date()) {
    timerLabel.text = timeElapsed
}
```

If five seconds has passed it pads all the zeros to make the string say `0:00:05`. However, I'm looking to make it say `0:05` for five seconds, `10:05` for 10 minutes and 5 seconds, and `1:10:05` for 1 hour, 10 minutes, and five seconds. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you should use dropLeading instead of pad.

Comment: Have you tried it with setting `collapsesLargestUnit` to true?

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I tried that but it just shows `5` for 5 seconds.

Comment: @Aseider Just tried it, but didn't seem to make a difference

Comment: You can count number of character 2 then add "0:\(timeElapsed)" ahead of  elased timeElapsed

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581717/datecomponentsformatter-drop-zero-hours-but-not-zero-minutes

Comment: @rmaddy thanks that worked

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of character is less than or equal 2 then append ahead of timeElapsed like this => "0:" + timeElapsed

```
var totalTime = ""
let startTime = Date().addingTimeInterval(-50)
let dateComponentsFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
dateComponentsFormatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
dateComponentsFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
dateComponentsFormatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .dropLeading
if let timeElapsed = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: startTime, to: Date()) {
    if timeElapsed.count <= 2 {
        totalTime = "0:" + timeElapsed
    }else {
        totalTime = timeElapsed
    }
    print(totalTime)
}
```

**Output**

```
0:50
```